# Cómo controlar la excepción "No se puede obtener acceso al objeto desechado"?

Tags: vb.net

estoy implementado sql dependency y todo funciona bien, excepto cuando cierro mi formulario (me lanza el mensaje: No se puede obtener acceso al objeto desechado). El error lo señala en el metodo OnNotificationChange pero no estoy segura de cómo cambiar el código dentro...
Les comparto los métodos involucrados que ya tengo:

---

```
 Private Sub OnNotificationChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
      SqlClient.SqlNotificationEventArgs)
        Me.Invoke(New UICallback(AddressOf FillGrid))
        StartChecking()
   End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub StartChecking()
        Dim cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = Nothing
        cn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(cs)

        Dim dad As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(QueryDependency, cn)

        Dim dependency As New SqlClient.SqlDependency(dad.SelectCommand)

        AddHandler dependency.OnChange, AddressOf Me.onNotificationChange

        SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(cs)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        dad.Fill(ds)
    End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub FillGrid()
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(cs)
            conn.Open()
            Using cm As New SqlCommand(QueryDependency, conn)
                Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cm)
                    Dim ds As New DataSet
                    adapter.Fill(ds)
                    grvRegistros.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        MuestraFoto()
End Sub
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que haces al cerrar el formulario? tal vez alcanzaria con desencajar el metodo OnNotificationChange cuando cerras asi evitas llamarlo cuando no hay formulario...

Comment: Gracias gbianchi, he reformulado la pregunta. Por otro lado, no comprendo a qué te refieres con "desencajar el método OnNotificationChange". Cuando cierro el formulario, sólo tengo la siguiente línea que detiene la dependencia: SqlDependency.Stop(cs)  ...pero después vuelve a entrar al evento OnNotificationChange y me marca el error antes mencionado en la línea:  Me.Invoke(New UICallback(AddressOf FillGrid))

Comment: esta linea: AddHandler dependency.OnChange, AddressOf Me.onNotificationChange, se ejecuta cada vez que ejecutas OnNotificationChange.. por lo tanto ese evento llama multiples veces a ese metodo.. tene en cuenta que vb no se fija quien controla el evento (por si agregas multiples funciones que lo esten mirando) si no, que agrega las funciones a las llamadas de ese evento.. hace un debug y fijate cuantas veces asignas ese metodo al evento. y por desencajar, me referia a sacar el controlador del evento (RemoveHandler), pero tene en cuenta que si esta varias veces, solo sacara 1...

Comment: Nuevamente gracias gbianchi, no tengo mucha experiencia usando manejadores de eventos pero con tus comentarios se me ocurrió implementar un try catch en el método OnNotificationChange removiendo el manejador cuando entra al catch y está funcionando correctamente. Comparto el código: Dim dependency As SqlDependency = CType(sender, SqlDependency)
 RemoveHandler dependency.OnChange, AddressOf OnNotificationChange